# Tool for Site Admins to manage their own Active Directory security groups?

Tags: 2010, web-part, active-directory

We are deploying a new SharePoint 2010 environment.  All access is controlled via Active Directory security groups (placed inside existing SharePoint groups).  Due to this, we are looking for a tool to manage users inside Active Directory security groups.

Do you know if there a 3rd party tool avaliable that will:

- Allow Site Admins to add existing users to existing Active Directory
  security groups
- Only show a certain subset of security groups that manager has
  'access' to limit the ability to create new users
- only allow for modification of existing security groups and members of
  that group

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

We have some people who manage AD security groups for some of our SharePoint sites and for other non SharePoint things.  We simply give them their group name and create a desktop shortcut to:

```
c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe dsquery, OpenQueryWindow
```

This opens up a windows interface to search for their group and add/remove users.

Comment: Say, I didn't know about that.  Can this open the window to a particular group?

Answer (score 0):

Quest Software provides wide array of tools to manage AD. You can pick those that meet your requirements: http://www.quest.com/active-directory/